# Warning: Cannot modify header information - WordPress issue

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm using WordPress 3.5.1 in my website,

I have copied this site into my local server for changes and everything went fine but suddenly after I uploaded my website to the public.html folder I get this error message when I try to use mysite.com:

> (Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/*****/public_html/wp-content/themes/andrina-lite/functions/theme-options.php:660) in /home/*****/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876)

But when I try `www.mysite.com` instead of `mysite.com` its opens but without the front page images that were uploaded by theme options.

Notes:

- in my local server all front page images had the same problem
- `*****` is my directory name and is hidden by me in this post

Comment: as per the near infinite number other dupe questions on this site with that exact same error message: your code has caused output BEFORE you do something that triggers an http header to be output. figure out where and correct the output.

Comment: Please read the error message... output started at **file** : **line**

Comment: Also you may check [this article](http://heera.it/headers-error-wordpress).

Answer (score 0):

At the line 660 of the theme-options.php file, you either have a white space between two PHP tags, or you're outputting (echoing) something.